# Hide/Show a Columns in Crosstable by using Ironpython

Tags: show-hide, ironpython, crosstab, spotfire

i new to spotfire,i never worked on iron-python script.i want hide the columns those are don't have values.

columns have to hide automatically based on value.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLhnl.jpg)

could you please help on this issue.

thanks for your help.

Thanks,
Basha

Comment: @Shaik- What is the criteria for show/hide columns? Also, have you tried using 'Show/hide items' option under properties for a table/cross table?

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have to create a report based on actual vs target. Actual values are monthly level and target at year level. I have attached sample report format.
Based on my knowledge we don’t have options to add dynamic columns in a report because of that I have added the all the month columns to report. Suppose if we are in Aug 2016 then it need to be hide Sep to Dec columns. We can Hide and Show columns in spotfire by using Iron-python script. 
Hide and show columns should be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to trigger the IronPython script on the dashboard being opened action. You need JavaScript for that. Such script can contain the current date and you can use the current date to hide the columns showing data for the months after current date.